# Make nested HTTP calls from a Service Class and return Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I need to make two dependent HTTP calls from my Service Class in Angular 5 and return an Observable so that my component can subscribe to it. So inside the Service Class function:

- HTTP call 1 will return some data, say, of type `string`
- This `string` will be used by HTTP call 2 as input
- HTTP call 2 returns, let's say a `string[]`
- Return type of the Service Class function will be of the type `Observable<string[]>`

Code that is not working (error: function must return a value):

```
getData(): Observable<string[]> {
  this.httpClient.get<string>('service1/getData').subscribe(
    dataFromSvc1 => {
      return this.httpClient.get<string[]>('service2/getData/' + dataFromSvc1);
    },
    err => {
      return throwError(err);
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: do you mean asynchronous?

Comment: No, synchronous. Result from call 1 is used in call 2

Comment: Just to be clear ... http is asynchronous. You submit a request ... and some time later it returns a response. What you are asking about is performing nested calls, correct?

Comment: To perform nested http calls, use a switchMap as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45926836/angular4-nested-http-calls/45926900

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953654/passing-concatmap-result-in-to-next-concatmap-in-rxjs/52953702#52953702

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try switchMap, something like this (NOT TESTED or syntax checked!):

```
getData(): Observable<string[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<string>('service1/getData')
    .pipe(
      switchMap(dataFromSvc1 => {
         return this.httpClient.get<string[]>('service2/getData/' + dataFromSvc1);
      }),
      catchError(this.someErrorHandler)
    );
}
```

The subscription then goes in the component calling this method.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. Edited your snippet to fix syntax.

Comment: Example : 
https://www.codeforeach.com/angular/angular-example-to-handle-nested-http-calls-in-service

Answer (score 3):

**mergeMap** or **switchMap** can be used in case of nested calls to get a single Observable as response.

```
getData(): Observable<string[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<string>('service1/getData').pipe(
    mergeMap( (dataFromSvc1) => {
      return this.httpClient.get<string[]>('service2/getData/' + dataFromSvc1);
    }),
    catchError( (err) => {
      // handle error scenario
    }
  )
}
```

Find the below article to check example code snippets for both Service and Component and step by step explanation of what happens when executed.

**https://www.codeforeach.com/angular/angular-example-to-handle-nested-http-calls-in-service**